# Wrapping text around a float while dynamically hiding overflow

Tags: css, css-float, overflow, word-wrap

So, there's plenty of advice about how to get text to not wrap around a float by using `overflow: hidden`, but there's no advice for how to do the opposite. I want text to wrap around an image, and hide the overflow that drops off the bottom of the box, so that I can reveal it later with a transition.

Here's my code that almost, almost works: http://jsfiddle.net/wzH49/

Comment: Wouldn't `overflow:hidden` on `.bookbox` do what you want though?

Comment: .... I suppose that does work... But it breaks my pretty little border at the bottom. Sigh, I guess I can't have everything.